# Forecast equation for ARIMA(0,1,q) in R

Tags: r, forecasting, arima

I am trying to figure out how R computes predictions for a fitted MA process of integration order 1. Consider the following trivial example of fitting an ARIMA(0,1,1) process to random data in R:

```
set.seed(12345)
y <- rnorm(100)
mod <-  Arima(y, order=c(0,1,1))
predict(mod, n.ahead = 1)
```

Relevant output:

```
> mod
Series: y 
ARIMA(0,1,1) 

Coefficients:
         ma1
      -1.000
s.e.   0.034

> predict(mod, n.ahead = 1)
$pred
Time Series:
Start = 101 
End = 101 
Frequency = 1 
[1] 0.2451972
```

I expected the predicted value to be given by:

$\hat{y}_{101} = y_{100} + \theta \hat{\varepsilon}_{100}$

which, in R, would be computed as:

```
> y[100] + mod$coef*mod$residuals[100]
      ma1 
0.2499258
```

Can anyone explain why this is different from the predicted value of 0.2452 given by the `predict` function?